# Can you hot reload multiple devices at once?

Tags: react-native

I have an iPod Touch and my Samsung Galaxy S4 hooked up with hot reloading enabled on both. However, the only one that will hot reload is whichever one was last to load the javascript.

Is there a way to get it working where they will both hot reload at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's coming...

Here's the pull requests:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6179

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7475

Click subscribe on the last one for updates.

Here's a video of it working :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etk3Bb7z1eQ

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7475#issuecomment-321918877) suggests that this feature is already in recent React Native versions.